# Starting Eclipse makes C program to crash immediately

Tags: c, eclipse, crash, malloc

I am working on the migration of a 20+ year old set of C programs (about 206,000 lines) from Solaris to RHEL (el6.x86_64).  On both architechture, the programs are compiled 32-bits.  One difference is that on Solaris, we use (cc) and on Linux we use (gcc).

There is a set of programs that monitor the list of all processes returned by the (ps –efj –ww) command in order to identify if a specific process has been called.  All the active processes are put into a linked list and scanned in order to find the specific process and its sub-processes among other things.  Then, after one minute, the linked list is cleared and the cycle restarts: the linked list of processes is build again.  This runs fine for weeks and months without a glitch, until we start Eclipse (Helios or Luna) from another user/session.  Then, our C program crashes with a Segmentation Fault, every time.  And here, we're not doing anything with Eclipse yet other than starting it.

How can this be possible?  As soon as Eclipse is being run by a user on the server (using X11/Putty), our C program, which is running from another user account (like a service account) is crashing immediately.

Thanks

Comment: There's probably something in the ps listing when Eclipse is running that causes a buffer overflow in your code (e.g. a char[] buffer that isn't big enough). Try running your code under valgrind to catch the bug.

Comment: If you can repeat the bug just by launching Eclipse, then you should be able to simply run your program through a debugger and see where it crashes?

Comment: The eclipse startup command is loooong. I bet it's a buffer overlow when reading/parsing(?) it.

Comment: "... crashes with a Segmentation Fault, every time." Consider yourself fortunate. Fortunate in that in all likelihood your program is invoking undefined behavior and doing so *predictably*. That is a not-so-subtle request for "Please attach a debugger to me, then launch Eclipse." And I'd crunch that thing under Valgrind as well. Chances are it isn't the only problem in that code.

Comment: (Or consider yourself fortunate because your program blocks Eclipse from executing. That's a pretty amazing program actually! It will make your life so much better.)

Comment: What is the relevant portion of the output of ``ps –efj –ww`` when Eclipse is running?

Comment: THANKS PAUL!   It was indeed a buffer overflow problem.  The -ww portion of the command returned a string way too big for the char[300] data structure item.  I changed the command for --width 200 and it's fine with some extra spaces left.